# Declaring an array in pseudocode

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

How can I declare the instantiation of an array of int of length 8 in pseudocode?
this means, how can I write the following code(Java) in pseudocode?
`int[] array = new int[8];`

Comment: You don't have to declare it.. If you insist, write it as you want.. as long as it's understandable :)

Comment: I would not even declare the array in pseudo-code. Like Maroun pointed out. The idea of pseudo-code is that is understandable 'code'. Even for non-programmers. It could come in handy while writing algorithms. For example if I were to write a loop through an array. I would say: for all elements in array of integers { do ... }. I usually do use curly brackets to make it more understandable. An example can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing#Pseudocode

Answer (score 2):

You can freely write in your own form, since Pseudocode has no standard definition. For example:

You can write

```
Declare an array of 8 integers
```

Or you can also write

Declare array(8) of integers

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE **NameOfArray**: ARRAY [**1st row**: **Last row**] OF **Datatype**

example:

DECLARE ListOfBuyers : ARRAY [0:1] OF STRING

Comment: What is the name of this pseudocode language ? Is it standardized or is it your creation?

Comment: It looks like Oxford Cambridge RSA standard Pseudocode